# How to prove $ \int_{B(0,1)}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|^{d-1}}dx<\infty $ if $ \int_{B(0,r)}|f(x)|^2dx\leq Cr^{\rho} $ for some $ \rho>d-2 $ and all $ 0<r<1 $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> Let $ f $ be a measurable function defined on $ \mathbb{R}^d $. Suppose that $ \int_{B(0,r)}|f(x)|^2dx\leq Cr^{\rho} $ for some $ \rho>d-2 $ and all $ 0<r<1 $, where $ C $ is a positive constant. Then
> \begin{eqnarray}
> \int_{B(0,1)}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|^{d-1}}\text{ }dx<\infty.
> \end{eqnarray}

I tried to control $ \int_{B(0,1)}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|^{d-1}}\text{ }dx $ by $ \int_{B(0,r)}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|^{d-1}}\text{ }dx $ and $ \int_{B(0,1)\backslash B(0,r)}\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|^{d-1}}\text{ }dx $, where $ 0<r<1 $ is a small number. However, I cannot deal with the first part by using the condition. Can you give me some hints and references?

Comment: My guess: The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: apply Cauchy-Schwarz. Then use the formula
\begin{align}
\int_{B(0,1)-B(0,r)}\frac{1}{|x|^{2(d-1)}}dx=\int_r^1 \left(\int_{\partial B(0,s)}\frac{1}{|x|^{2(d-1)}}dS \right)ds=\alpha(n)\int_r^1 \frac{1}{s^{2(d-1)}}s^{d-1}ds
\end{align}
You should be able to put this all together with the facts about $f$ to obtain a bound as $r\to 0$.